# GitLab CI: Is it possible to run parallel jobs in different runner

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm looking for a way to run parallels jobs in different runners. I have several powerful runners set up for GitLab CI. In general, it's ok to run jobs on the same runner because they're executed in Docker container.

However, now I have a Pipeline that jobs are executed in parallel and each job consumes lots of CPU and Mem.(it's by design, not an issue). If it's unlucky that GitLab CI schedules those jobs to the same runner, job fails.

And, I want this limitation applies to this project ONLY, as my runners have 30+ CPU and 120GB+ Memory.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, if you have set up say two runners (either specific, shared or group runners) with tags.

Say, runner1 has tags `runner1-ci`, `my-runner1`

Similarly, runner2 has tags `runner2-ci`, `my-runner2`

Now, in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, you can use the tags like below, so a job will pick up that particular runner and execute the job.

```yaml
image: maven:latest

    stages:
      - build
      - test
      - deploy

    install_dependencies:
      stage: build
      tags:
      - runner1-ci
      script:
         - pwd
         - echo "Build"
    
    test:
      stage: test
      tags:
      - runner2-ci
      script:
         - echo "Testing"
         
    deploy:
      stage: deploy
      tags:
      - runner1-ci
      script:
         - echo "Deploy to nexus"
```

> Note: This is just an example `.gitlab-ci.yml` to demonstrate the use of `tags` in pipeline.